# Символ решетки в url

Tags: c#, asp.net, vkontakte-api

Добрый день! Есть вопрос по авторизации сайта в vk api. В документации говорится следующее:

> После успешной авторизации приложения браузер пользователя будет перенаправлен по адресу REDIRECT_URI, указанному при открытии диалога авторизации. При этом ключ доступа к API access_token и другие параметры будут переданы в URL-фрагменте ссылки:
>
> http://REDIRECT_URI#access_token= 533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492

Я использую сайт на asp.net. 
Проблема в том, что после REDIRECT_URI, как можно видеть, идет символ '#' вместо '?', как это обычно бывает, в url, чтобы показать, что дальше идет список параметров. Поэтому когда я на своем сайте пытаюсь отладживать страницу, указанную в REDIRECT_URI, то не могу получить доступ к параметрам запроса. Они оказываются пустыми. А вот если перейти по url

> http://REDIRECT_URI?access_token= 533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492

то все в порядке и параметры отображаются в переменной `Request.QueryString`. 
Как правильно распарсить параметры запроса в таком случае?

Comment: Добрый день, посмотрите ответы вот на этот вопрос, надеюсь поможет ) [Как получить параметры из URL?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433889/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-url/598795#598795)

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить только то, что вам придется распарсить строку средствами JavaScript. нужные данные хранятся в `window.location.hash`

Comment: Проблема в том, что доступа к клиенту у меня нет. Этот redirect_uri приходит от вконтакте, который редиректит запрос на мой сайт, и уже на мой сайт приходит запрос с решеткой.

Comment: а использование клиентского способа авторизации обязательное условие? в серверном варианте возвращает в привычном виде

Comment: а что за клиентский и серверный виды авторизации?

Comment: в документации API vk есть описание.
Попробуйте посмотреть здесь http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread565785.html