# Как получить параметры из URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vkontakte-api

При авторизации через API ВКонтакте происходит переадресация на URL вида:

> http://localhost:58821/Auth#access_token=123456712345123451234512345&expires_in=0&user_id=1234567

Обращение к `Request.Url.AbsolutePath`, `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` или `Request.RawUrl` даёт только ссылку на хост. Как я могу получить параметры из данного URL?
Upd.: Вероятно проблема в том что адрес и get параметры разделяются символом '#', а не '?', поэтому параметры получить не получается. Можно ли как-то получить всю строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ошиблись при выборе типа авторизации - вам необходимо использовать авторизацию предназначенную не для [мобильных приложений](http://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile)(клиентскую), а для [сайтов](http://vk.com/dev/auth_sites)(серверную).

При этом, необходимо что бы ваш веб-сервер был доступен извне - если не по домену, то хотя бы по какому-то публичному ip. С `localhost` серверную авторизацию использовать не получится.

Если бы это у вас был клиентский код, то можно было бы добавить себе в проект сборку `System.Web` и использовать код вроде такого:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:58821/Auth#access_token=123&expires_in=0&user_id=456");
var fragment = uri.Fragment.TrimStart('#');    // access_token=123&expires_in=0&user_id=456
var access_token = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(fragment).Get("access_token");    // 123
```

Однако у вас сайт на ASP.NET, и фрагмент(часть Uri начинающаяся с '#') из серверного кода вы не получите никак - клиентом он не передаётся.

В вашем случае использовать авторизацию для мобильных устройств нельзя. Точнее конечно можно выпрашивать у пользователя их настоящие логин/пароль, передавать их вместо пользователя, авторизовывать своё приложение, да сохранять токен - но это плохо попахивает, и обязательно вызовет недоверие у пользователей.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо за пояснения. Возможно Вы сможете помочь ещё в одном вопросе: мне нужно глобальный осуществить поиск по постам в вкнонтакте (задача - нахождение упоминаний компании), для этого хорошо подходит метод api "getHint", но он не доступен для сайтов. Возможно подскажете выход или замену данному методу? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Uran_90, для этой задачи скорей подходит `newsfeed.search` - не требующий никакой авторизации метод, который собственно и находит упоминание указанных слов в постах вконтакте. А `search.getHint` предназначен прежде всего для вывода "поисковой подсказки" - он ищет не по постам, а по названиям и описаниям групп, публичных страниц, и пользователей - при этом люди и группы на которые текущий пользователь подписан выводятся всегда первыми, не смотря возможно низкую релевантность.

Comment: Ещё раз большое спасибо за подсказку, Сергей

Answer (score 2):

Два дня убил на то, чтобы решить для себя эту проблему, в итоге решил, правда у меня сервер на java но я думаю это не будет особо большой проблемой для понимания. **сервер работает на localhost!**

итак по шагам:
1 - в vk на странице с настройками приложения нужно включить openAPI и в настройках хостов прописать localhost и страницу на которую будет редирект из метода https://oauth.vk.com/authorize в параметре **redirect_uri** у меня это выглядит вот так
[image: настройка приложения]

2 - нужно использовать серверную авторизацию а не клиентскую: [ссылка на vk.api](https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user) т.е. для начала нужно получить **code**

```
getCode {
    @Override
    public String getExactMethod() {
        return "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?"
                + "client_id=" + AppProperty.properties.getProperty("vk.client.id")
                + "&scope=market"
                + "&display=popup"
                + "&redirect_uri=" + AppProperty.properties.getProperty("vk.client.uri.local")
                + "&response_type=code"
                + "&v=5.60";
    }
}
```

таким образом в ответе придет код как обчыный get параметр. я его получаю и обрабатываю в фильтре присваивая константе класса

3 - получив код можно отправлять GET запрос на https://oauth.vk.com/access_token используя HttpClient у меня это выглядит вот так:
формирование запроса

```
getAccessToken {
    @Override
    public String getExactMethod() {
        return "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?"
                + "client_id=" + AppProperty.properties.getProperty("vk.client.id")
                + "&client_secret=" + AppProperty.properties.getProperty("vk.client.secure.key")
                + "&redirect_uri=" + AppProperty.properties.getProperty("vk.client.uri.local")
                + "&code=" + code;
    }
}
```

где **code** уже присвоен с прошлого этапа, затем я отправляю сам запрос:

```
public Object sendGetRequest(SimpleRequest request) {
    HttpGet postRequest = new HttpGet(request.getUri());
    JSONObject vkApiJsonResponse = null;
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
         CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest)){

        String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        vkApiJsonResponse = new JSONObject(json_string);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Ошибка.", e.getMessage()));
    }
    return vkApiJsonResponse;
}
```

в результате которого возвращается JSON объект, который и содержит токен, срок его жизни и user_id, вот пример возвращаемого значения из моего дебага

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4 - profit! :)
надеюсь это сэкономит кому ни будь пару бессоных ночей/долгих дней.
Всем добра!

Answer (score 0):

Для получения параметров можно использовать `QueryString`

```
if ( Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("user_id") )
{
      var id = Request.QueryString["user_id"];
}
```

Comment: Вероятно проблема в том что адрес и get параметры разделяются символом '#', а не '?', поэтому массив Request.QueryString пустой

Answer (score 0):

В ASP.NET есть объект Request, который содержит в себе данные, связанные с текущим запросом. В частности, и параметры запроса тоже. Главный способ их получения - это использование свойства QueryString, представляющее собой коллекцию ключей и значений. Можно также использовать индексатор класса Request например так:

```
Request["myparam"]
```

но в случае с индексатором данные по ключу ищутся не только  среди параметров url'а, но еще и среди параметров формы, кук и серверных переменных.

Comment: Вероятно проблема в том что адрес и get параметры разделяются символом '#', а не '?', поэтому Request["access_token"] даёт null.

Answer (score 0):

Часть запроса после # (якорь) может не отправляться на сервер. Получить доступ к "якорю" можно на клиенте через javascript и отправить её, например, на сервер для обработки.

JavaScript:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

JQuery:

```
var hash = $(location).attr('hash').substring(1);
```

Comment: Хм, а за что минус?

Comment: @VladD возможно, кого-то огорчило, что варианты `window.location.hash.substring(1)` и `$(location).attr('hash')` выдают разные результаты.

Comment: Да и использование jQuery в данном случае не даёт никаких преимуществ.

Comment: А у вас тут строго